# Access private appointments in a shared calendar from Outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices

I develop an Outlook VSTO add-in in C#. I need to read existing appointments from shared calendars to see busy time slots. I have the publishing editor permission over all shared calendars and it's working with non-private appointments seamlessly.

My only problem is that *CalendarFolder.Items* collection does not contain appointment items having *olPrivate* or *olPersonal* Sensitivity setting. 
While the built-in Outlook calendar view shows these items with the little lock icon.

I understand that private appointments expose only Start and End times and it would be absolutely enough for me.

The underlying Exchange server version is 2013. We use Outlook 2013 and 2016.

Any idea what can cause this?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE:

Finally I found a solution for this problem by using [EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
// ...... 
ExchangeService EWSService = new ExchangeService();
EWSService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("EXCHUser", "EXCHPW");
EWSService.Url = new Uri("https://...../EWS/Exchange.asmx");

Mailbox primary = new Mailbox(Tools.MainWindow.SelectedConsultant.Email);
var calendar = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder.Bind(EWSService, 
               new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, primary));
ItemView cView = new ItemView(100);

// Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, 
//                       start time, end time and sensitivity.
cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, 
                                    AppointmentSchema.Start, 
                                    AppointmentSchema.End, 
                                    AppointmentSchema.Sensitivity);

// Filter by sensitivity and retrieve a collection of appointments by using the item view.
String SearchFilterValue = Sensitivity.Private.ToString();
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Sensitivity, SearchFilterValue);
FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = calendar.FindItems(filter, cView);
foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
{
    if (a.Sensitivity == Sensitivity.Private)
    {
        // Do what you want with the matched item
    }
}
// ......
```

Comment: Keep in mind that EWS requires you provide the credentials, and, since you are working with an online mailbox, the data might be out of sync with what you see in Outlook. The data is there locally, you just need to bypass OOM with Extended MAPI or Redemption.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you. In my current situation it is an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. There is nothing special about these appointments, and their properties are still accessible using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi). If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option (it wraps Extended MAPI and can be used from any language), its [RDOAppointment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAppointmenItem.htm) object (which can be retrieved from [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm)) will return all available properties.

Can you see the data on the MAPI level if you look at it using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am also its author - click IMessage button or click IMAPIFolder button and open the appointments from the GetContentsTable tab)?

Comment: Thank you Dimitry, I have OutlookSpy (great work)! No I cannot use OutlookSpy in this case because I cannot even select the item in the calendar folder, it won't get focus at all.

Comment: You can still click IMAPIFolder, go to the GetContentsTable tab and open the appointment from there.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I can see it. It is listed as _IPM.Appointment_ in the left side. PR_SENSITIVITY has values 2 (SENSITIVITY_PRIVATE). PR_START_DATE and PR_END_DATE have meaningful values.

Comment: Finally I managed to solve it by using EWA Managed API 2.0. I'll give a separate answer to my question and include the code. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Sorry for the typo: I meant EWS, Exchange Web Services.